# adding a value of group by function

Tags: mysql

```
select 
  id
 ,rnwfees1
 ,count(cd.subscriberid) as cnt
 ,sum(revenue) as actalamt 
 ,TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,commisiondate,now())+1 as cnt
 ,renewalfee*(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,commisiondate,now())+1) as expected 
From corporatesubscribers cs 
inner join po_location pl on pl.wo_no=cs.workorderid and pl.loc_code=cs.loc_code 
inner join special_plans sp on cs.packageid=sp.packageid 
inner join corporatedisbursement cd on cd.subscriberid=cs.cosubid 
where cs.workorderid='WOPO/0005/TN/0002' 
group by cd.id
```

.

```
id |rnwfees1 | cnt | actalamt | cnt   | expected |    
1  | 2199.00 | 14  | 30786.00 |    21 | 46179.00 |    
2  | 2199.00 | 14  | 30786.00 |    20 | 43980.00 |
3  | 2199.00 | 14  | 30786.00 |    20 | 43980.00 |    
4  | 2199.00 | 14  | 30786.00 |    22 | 48378.00 |    
5  | 2199.00 | 14  | 30786.00 |    21 | 46179.00 |
```

I want the sum(actalamt). I tried it.

Comment: sorry I need sum(expected)

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're looking for `WITH ROLLUP` modifier. Here's a doc: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html